# deleting duplicates based on value of another column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table with 3 columns and the first column is 'name'. Some names are entered twice, some 3 times and some more than that. I would like to keep only one value for each name and delete the extra rows based on the values of Column 2 and 3. If column 2 and 3 are null, I would like to delete that row.
There are no primary keys or id column.
There are about 2.75 million rows in the table.
Would like to delete using one query(preferably) in SQL 14. Can someone help please?

```
Name    column2 column3
Suzy    english  null
Suzy    null    null
Suzy    null     5
John    null    null
John    7        7
George  null    benson
George  null    null
George  benson  null    
George  5       benson
```

Would like to have it as:

```
Name    column2 column3
Suzy    english  null   
Suzy    null     5  
John     7       7
George  benson   null
George  5        benson
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't there be one more George row? One row with `George, benson, null` and another row with `George, null, benson` plus the last one with `5, benson`.

Comment: You could also look at controlling the way data is added to the table so you don't have to do this clean up in the first place ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use partitions over name with the appropriate order by:

```
WITH cte as (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER()
    OVER (PARTITION BY name
          ORDER BY case
            when column1 = 'null' and column2 = 'null' then 3
            when column2 = 'null' then 2
            when column1 = 'null' then 1
            else 0 end
    ) num 
  FROM mytable
)
delete from cte where num > 1
```

This deletes duplicates, keeping in order of preference, rows with:

1. both column1 and column2 not null (random one kept if there are multiple of these)
2. column1 not null
3. column2 not null
4. both column1 and column2 null

Note that is query assumes (based on comments to question) that your "null" values are actually the text string "null" and not an SQL `null`.

If they were actually nulls, replace `= 'null'` with `IS NULL`.

Comment: why we need column2='null' , column1 ='null'

Comment: @thegame to break ties, logic based on example data in question. See edited answer for more detail

Answer (score 0):

```
Delete from yourtable 
where column2 is null and column3 is null
```

above query is Based on this..

> I would like to keep only one value for each name and delete the extra rows based on the values of Column 2 and 3. If column 2 and 3 are null, I would like to delete that row

Comment: Thanks but the slight problem is, if i do a serach for 
Select * from mytable 
where column2 is null and column3 is null

It is coming up with nothing. but if i do
Select * from mytable 

I can see the 2 null columns!!
Don't know how to resolve the issue

Comment: Are those actual `NULL`s or the string "null"?  They are completely different

Comment: What do if the only row for a name has null(s) for the other columns(s)?

Comment: How do I find that out? It is NULL, as far as I can see. Didn't create the table. It has been in existence for a long time.

Comment: @Suzy:to find just use   select * from table where column2 ='null' and column3='null'